# [AADSTS65001]: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application

Tags: c#, adal

I am writing a test application which uses AAD to get acquire token, and this call succeeds for one user with TenantId "abc" but fails for another user with tenantId "xyz" with the message:

> The user or administrator has not consented to use the application
>   with ID `f5986c14-cdb9-4e68-a89e-119d15b33afc`. Send an interactive
>   authorization request for this user and resource.

Please note:

1. I have created one native application in my AAD
2. I have added those users from another tenant into the Users list of the directory as User role and also, we granted the permissions for the native app to all the users in the directory in windows azure management portal [Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbZj.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 4):

The IT administrator of the company with xyz domain (email@xyz.onmicrosoft.com) has to give consent on behalf of the whole company so that the users of that company will be able to use your application. Here is a very good example of the flow:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes, we read this doc and it looks like it only applies to web application. How about native applications? Our application type is native application.  

For native application, it is a little different, I think.

Comment: @Priyaa It's the same flow for both native and web applications.

Answer (score 2):

No matter native application and web application, if you want to enable the users on other tenant can use the application, the application required to give the consent first. And the figure you linked in the post only grant the permission for the tenant the app register.

AidaNow already provided using the adal.js to grant the admin consent. We also can make a HTTP request to grant the admin consent easily by using the `prompt` parameter. Here is the request for your reference(refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&state=12345
&prompt=admin_consent
```

More detail about consent, you can refer the document below:

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#related-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried the command abov, but when i login, i get following error "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request."

Comment: Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 897e130f-5cf9-499c-9243-d095456a8ea3
Timestamp: 2017-06-13 17:19:27Z
AADSTS50001: The application named https://scheduler.teams.microsoft.com/ was not found in the tenant named skypetestsyt0mngc.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: URl tried: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=f5986c14-cdb9-4e68-a89e-119d15b33afc
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fscheduler.teams.microsoft.com%2F
&state=12345
&prompt=admin_consent

Comment: The error indicates that the application  https://scheduler.teams.microsoft.com doesn't exits in the target tenant. If the app were developed by your company, you need to add the  native app's App ID as a `knownClientApplications` for the https://scheduler.teams.microsoft.com application. If the application was developed by other company, please grant the permission for that app first in the target tenant using the request above. Feel free to let know if you still have the problem and check the link in the post, it is very helpful to understand multi-tenant application developing

Comment: In-addition, if the application https://scheduler.teams.microsoft.com was developed by your company, please make sure that enable the multi-tenant so that it can be used by other tenant.